# How to generate compatible PDF and RTF(with proper styles) file from ftl template (Freemarker java)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, freemarker

I have a .ftl template, from this I am able to send mail.
PDF and RTF are generated from same .ftl file. But same output is not generated.
When I change table css styles, sometimes, PDF output is correct, but sometimes RTF output is correct.
For **PDF** Generation:

```
 Configuration freemarkerConfig = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29);
    freemarkerConfig.setWhitespaceStripping(false);
    
 URL fileResource = FreeMarkerController.class.getResource("/templates");
    Map<String, Object> globalModel = new HashMap<>();
        globalModel.put("Company", "test");
        globalModel.put("First Name", "test");
        globalModel.put("Last Name", "trst");

Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("simpleForm.ftl");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
t.process(globalModel, stringWriter);
String content = stringWriter.toString();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, stream);
        document.open();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(content));
        document.close();

String downloadFileName = "form" + ".pdf";
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadFileName + "\"");
        response.setContentLength(stream.toByteArray().length);
        FileCopyUtils.copy(stream.toByteArray(), response.getOutputStream());
```

[image: PDF output is attached]

---

For **RTF** Generation

```
freemarkerConfig.setWhitespaceStripping(false);
        freemarkerConfig.setSetting("output_format", "RTF");
    
    Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("simpleForm.ftl", "UTF-8");
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    t.process(globalModel, stringWriter);
    String content = stringWriter.toString();
            
    String downloadFileName = "simpleForm"+ ".rtf";;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/rtf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+downloadFileName+"\"");
    response.setContentLength(content.getBytes().length);
    stream1.write(content.getBytes());
    FileCopyUtils.copy(stream1.toByteArray(), response.getOutputStream());
```

[image: RTF output is attached]

I am not sure what I am missing.
Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should tell what library are you using to convert XHTML to PDF and to RTF. Or at least I assume that the output of `simpleForm.ftl` is XHTML. Then you should show some minimal concrete problematic cases with the XHTML behind them. Also, doesn't the RTF generator code you show just sends the XHTML as is, and calling it RTF?

Comment: I think your problem is not in freemarker, but in the CSS of your page which is interpreted differently between your PDF generation tool and the RTF reader.